# Why did the north / south runways close at Daugherty Field (KLGB)?

Tags: airport, runways, airport-design, closed-runways

The north / south runway at KLGB were recently closed.  Does anyone know the reason for the runway closures?

[image: KLGB Airport Diagram]

Comment: I'm looking at the notams and it has 12/30 closed from 09/13/2016 to 09/17/2016. The notam doesn't say why, but that its only closed from 0500 to 1315 daily for 4 days. A little more searching shows that they've been doing it in pieces since at least July, and it looks like runway maintenance/construction. On the FAA site there is a link to a ["Construction Diagram"](https://nfdc.faa.gov/xwiki/bin/download/NFDC/Construction+Notices/lgb.pdf) but the link is broken. Looks like they are also working on the ALS for a couple of those days.

Comment: @RonBeyer -- the querent's referring to the 16/34s not 12/30

Comment: That may make more sense, I didn't notice it because it's not notam'd out. http://www.lbflying.com/files/lbaa2008-2.pdf suggests that they have closed it because of a geometry issue. The runways were unlit, in need of repair, and not frequently used. It also added a lot of confusion to the already complex airport movement areas, so they were closed after a 2 year study.

Comment: So I did 35 hours of my flight training from this airfield in '01 and not once in 4 weeks did I hear or see of the N/S runways being used. You just bought back some fond memories of Daugherty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a [Long Beach Post](https://lbpost.com/news/2000005042-long-beach-airport-runway-removal) article:

> The two runways in question have not been in operation for a number of years and the study ultimately found that removing them will create a safer and more efficient airport for the City of Long Beach.
>
> The removal will allow for new taxiways and possibly opportunities for economic development.

It seems by checking the summer (June) **wind rose** for Long Beach—shown below—the longest runway 30-12 has the best wind averages, even when the southerly wind dominates the month. It would be cheaper to use than to maintain two old ailing runways.

[image]
([Source](http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/ftpref/downloads/climate/windrose/california/long_beach/)) 30-12 runway drawn over the wind rose.

Comment: What about the summer wind rose?  EDIT: It appears that the summer one is the one you have there; the December rose looks considerably different from that.

Comment: @Sean - fixed, thanks.